# Export to CAD: How to prevent ArcGIS Pro 2.01 from adding results to Map/TOC?

Tags: export, arcgis-pro, autocad, cad

How can I prevent ArcGIS Pro 2.01 from adding "Export to CAD" results to Map/TOC? 
This is easily done in legacy ArcGIS Desktop in Geoprocessing options and unchecking the "Add results of geoprocessing operations to the display"

I don't see this option in Pro but perhaps there is another way this can be done?

I have 2 issues with specifically the Export to CAD tool:

1. Results are not grouped and when automatically added to Map/TOC this creates a mess and since I am typically not interested in adding the exported CAD data back into the map I always remove it.  Furthermore, the fact that even adding CAD data to map does not create a group layer as we are used to from legacy ArcGIS Desktop is highly inconvenient.
2. There appears to be a bug (have not reported this yet) - after adding CAD fields to feature class layers, then populating them values in attempts to customize the output CAD file, the Export to CAD tool succeeds but during the process of the resulting CAD layers being added to the Map/TOC the TOC crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way currently is to run the following command in the Python window:

```
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False
```

Answer (score 0):

I just save all of my work first. Then Export to CAD. Then close the map without saving the changes.